# RxJava: restart from the beginning on each subscription

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java

Imagine I have some time consuming task which I want to run only occasionally.

I want to wrap it into an observable and pass it to some component.
That component will subscribe to this observable whenever it wants to retrieve the data, and unsubscribe after it receives it.

I.e. I want an observable which upon subscription would invoke some expensive API call, and this API call can return a **different data** each time it is called - and then this observable would shut down until next subscription is made.

Is this possible to achieve?

I have seen 'replay()' and 'cache()' operators, but they won't work because from what I understood, they will cache once and then replay cached values which fails my case of changing data.

Also there is 'observable.publish()' but it seems that this will make a hot observable which will stay connected to the source observable all the time...

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, you need a cold observable.

```
   Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.from(1, 2, 3, 4);
   obs.subscribe(); // will iter over values
   obs.subscribe(); // will iter AGAIN over values
```

So, if your observable is your api call, and it's a cold observable, just subscribe twice on it to perform two api calls.

Comment: Hm. So If I subscribe to observable which already had called it's onCompleted() method, it will be restarted? I thought that any subscriptions which happen after observable completion will get nothing. Need to check this out, thanks.

Comment: If it's a cold Observable, for every Subscriber it is initialized, goes through its logic, calling onNext when it should and completes.